# Is there any such inequality in nilpotent subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a nilpotent group and $H,K$ be  two any proper subgroups of $G$.

$$N_G(H^K)> K $$

Is this inequality true ?

**Note:** $H^K=\langle\{H^k|k\in K\}\rangle$

Comment: @whacka: Or they are both $G$. Sorry, they are proper As I am trying to see whether normiizer grows in that way.

Comment: If we take $K=N_G(H)$, then $H^K=H$, and we get equality.

Comment: @DerekHolt : I cant believe that it is that simple. Thanks :)